# Given campground array, write a function that returns a string and matching number

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been given a campgrounds array and I need to write a function, findMyCampsites() with parameters, (campgrounds, view, partySize). I need to filter out the ones that are unreserved, then return an array with campsite numbers for the matching campsites.

Example: `findMyCampsites(campgrounds, 'ocean', 8) //-> [1]`

And if the input is one that is not in the array it will return 'Sorry, no campsites with that view are available to host your party'.

Example: `findMyCampsites(campgrounds, 'forest', 6) //-> 'Sorry, no campsites with that view are available to host your party'`

Given array:

```
let campgrounds = [
  { number: 1, view: 'ocean', partySize: 8, isReserved: false },
  { number: 5, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 12, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
  { number: 18, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 23, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: true }
];
```

What I have so far:

```
function findMyCampsites(campgrounds, view, partySize) {
  let total = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++) {
    if (campgrounds[i].view === view) {
      total++;
    }
    return total;
  }
}
```

I know I need to return the campsite's number that is available and that can fit the party size and which have their desired view, but I don't know what to do after the for loop..

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do here. Are you returning the number of matching campsites or an array with the numbers for each of the matching campsites?

Answer (score 1):

Just add another condition for the `pageSize` and `isReserved`:

```js
let campgrounds = [
  { number: 1, view: 'ocean', partySize: 8, isReserved: false },
  { number: 5, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 12, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
  { number: 18, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 23, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: true }
];

function findMyCampsites(campgrounds, view, partySize) {
  let campsites = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++) {
    if (campgrounds[i].view === view && campgrounds[i].partySize == partySize && !campgrounds[i].isReserved) {
      campsites.push(campgrounds[i].number);
    }
  }
  return campsites.length>0 ? 
    campsites 
    : 'Sorry, no campsites with that view are available to host your party';
}

console.log(findMyCampsites(campgrounds, 'ocean', 8));
console.log(findMyCampsites(campgrounds, 'forest', 6));
```

Again, you can easily achieve this with `.filter`:

```js
let campgrounds = [
  { number: 1, view: 'ocean', partySize: 8, isReserved: false },
  { number: 5, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 12, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
  { number: 18, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 23, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: true }
];

function findMyCampsites(campgrounds, view, partySize) {
  let campsites = campgrounds.filter(campground =>
    (campground.view === view && campground.partySize == partySize && !campground.isReserved)
  ).map(e => e.number);
  return campsites.length>0 ? 
    campsites 
    : 'Sorry, no campsites with that view are available to host your party';
}

console.log(findMyCampsites(campgrounds, 'ocean', 8));
console.log(findMyCampsites(campgrounds, 'forest', 6));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter method to iterate through each element of the array and filter by different properties

```js
function findMyCampsites(campgrounds, view, partySize) {
   const camp = campgrounds.filter(
      camp => camp.view == view 
         && camp.partySize == partySize 
         && camp.isReserved == false)

   return camp.length >= 1 ? camp.length : "No campsites where found"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner using [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and [assignment returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Return_value_and_chaining):

```js
let findMyCampsite = (campgrounds, view, partySize) => (
  (res = campgrounds.filter(cg => (
    !cg.isReserved && partySize <= cg.partySize && view === cg.view
  )).map(({ number }) => number)).length > 0 ? res : 'Sorry, no campsites with that view are available to host your party'
)

let campgrounds = [
  { number: 1, view: 'ocean', partySize: 8, isReserved: false },
  { number: 5, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 12, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
  { number: 18, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 23, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: true }
];

console.log(findMyCampsite(campgrounds, 'ocean', 4));
console.log(findMyCampsite(campgrounds, 'ocean', 9));
```